# Import format to intellij idea from JSMin/JSFormat

Tags: intellij-idea, notepad++, jsmin

Does anybody knows which formatting rules uses jsmin/jsformatter plugin of Notepad++? I need this because we are forced to use this formatter but I'm using intellij idea to write js code. So having this rules I can import it some how or, at least, apply manually.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The minimising rules applied are listed here:

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

> JSMin is a filter that omits or modifies some characters. This does
>   not change the behavior of the program that it is minifying. The
>   result may be harder to debug. It will definitely be harder to read.
>
> JSMin first replaces carriage returns ('\r') with linefeeds ('\n'). It
>   replaces all other control characters (including tab) with spaces. It
>   replaces comments in the // form with linefeeds. It replaces comments
>   in the /* */ form with spaces. All runs of spaces are replaced with a
>   single space. All runs of linefeeds are replaced with a single
>   linefeed.
>
> It omits spaces except when a space is preceded and followed by a
>   non-ASCII character or by an ASCII letter or digit, or by one of these
>   characters:
>
> \ $ _
>
> It is more conservative in omitting linefeeds, because linefeeds are
>   sometimes treated as semicolons. A linefeed is not omitted if it
>   precedes a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or one of
>   these characters:
>
> \ $ _ { [ ( + -
>
> and if it follows a non-ASCII character or an ASCII letter or digit or
>   one of these characters:
>
> \ $ _ } ] ) + - " '
>
> No other characters are omitted or modified.

There are other custom formatting rules applied according to the plugin developer's page:

http://www.sunjw.us/jsminnpp/